# PHP undefined index with xammp but not with host

Tags: php, post, xampp

I've made this php file and I've uploaded it to my free host. It works fine. When I don't submit the form, it just displays nothing. (here you can see it: http://tuku.net63.net/test.php)

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="name"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>

<?php
    echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

But now I've uploaded exactly the same file to my xammp server, and when I don't submit the form, it displays this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7
```

Has it something to do with the PHP settings? I don't know?

Thanx!

Comment: at the beginning `error_reporting(0)`; Or read everything on [php.net](http://php.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your development server has Warnings turned off, this is very bad!

Your production server has Warnings turned on, this is *potentially* bad.

On development use: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get all errors and warnings. Also make sure you've got "display_errors" set to true. `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: I think you understood the opposite. OP says xammp server displays the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't submit anything, `$_POST['name']` is undefined. You should check if it's set:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

Your free host is probably setup not to show errors, that's why you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The Notice is correct. You have not submitted the form and there is no `$_POST`;

Comment: I know, but why it's only with my xampp server and not with the host?

Answer (score 0):

@Heroking in PHP there is a highly customizable error reporting system.Using that you can set which all errors to display such as Notice,Warning,Error,fatal Error,startup error etc...In production server configuration(the configuration of host) all types of error reporting will be turned off for security reasons because it makes it easy for public to see the error and make an outline of the code.Also its very annoying to see the errors(that too as unformatted plain text) in the middle of the beautiful webpage...

But in a development server configuration such as xamp,wamp and other most of the error reporting options will be enabled by default.this helps in debugging the PHP code.This is the reason why you see error in your home development server but not on host server.